# How to generate an image from WKT?

Tags: raster, .net, well-known-text, well-known-binary

I am looking to programatically generate an image from a WKT string (or any other common format, such as WKB or SQL Spatial geography). Are there any existing libraries that allow for this? I am working in .Net, but I am open to anything. The idea is that I could generate dynamic tile layers with the images instead of having to load up my Silverlight UI with heavy vector layers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MapScript](http://www.mapserver.org/mapscript/) (part of [MapServer](http://www.mapserver.org/)) to make images from any sort of geometry. With (e.g.) [MapScript for PHP](http://www.mapserver.org/mapscript/php/), you could build a geometry from a WKT string with `ShapeObj ms_shapeObjFromWkt(string wkt)`, make the style look good, then render an image object with `imageObj draw()` (see an [example](http://www.mapserver.org/mapscript/php/by_example.html)).

There are different flavours of Mapscript, including for .NET ([docs](http://mapserver.org/installation/dotnet.html), [tutorial](http://www.paolocorti.net/2006/09/20/mapserver-tutorial-for-c-mapscript-asp-net/)), but it might be too old. The documentation for PHP is the best, and is similar for the other scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

Mapserver, Mapnik, GeoServer, ArcGIS Server are the usual suspects.